# Terraform AzureRM Continually Modifying API Management with Proxy Configuration for Default Endpoint

Tags: terraform, azure-api-management, azure-rm

We are terraforming our Azure API Management instance.

```
...
resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  name                = "the-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name

...

  hostname_configuration {
    proxy {
      host_name = "the-apim.azure-api.net"
      negotiate_client_certificate = true
    }
  }
}
...
```

We need to include the `hostname_configuration` block so that we can switch `negotiate_client_certificate` to true for the default endpoint.

This does the job, however every time Terraform runs it plans to modify the APIM instance by adding the `hostname_configuration` block again:

```
      + hostname_configuration {

          + proxy {
              + host_name                    = "the-apim.azure-api.net"
              + negotiate_client_certificate = true
            }
        }
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? In the portal I can see this value is set to true.

Comment: So this leads to a replacement of the instance after each `apply`?

Comment: It doesn't lead to replacement but it does lead to the resource being 'changed' every time. It's more of a hygiene thing than an actual issue - I don't really want any changes to be planned if nothing is required.

Comment: Those "ghost" changes are known for years. Here is [one issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8800) on GH still open after 3 years without a solution. Your case could be similar.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, can you please explain more!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try to pair with [`lifecycle > ignore_changes`](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle).

> The ignore_changes feature is intended to be used when a resource is created with references to data that may change in the future, but should not affect said resource after its creation. In some rare cases, settings of a remote object are modified by processes outside of Terraform, which Terraform would then attempt to "fix" on the next run. In order to make Terraform share management responsibilities of a single object with a separate process, the ignore_changes meta-argument specifies resource attributes that Terraform should ignore when planning updates to the associated remote object.

In your case, the `hostname_configuration` is considered a "nested block" or "attribute as block" in Terraform. So the usage of `ignore_changes` is not so straightforward (you can't just add the property name, as you would do if you wanted to ignore changes in your `resource_group_name` for example, which is directly a property). From an [issue in GitHub back from 2018](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3819#issuecomment-374239422), it seems you could use the TypeSet hash of the nested block to add to an ignore sections.

Even though I can't test this, my suggestion for you:

1. deploy your `azurerm_api_management` resource normally with the `hostname_configuration` block
2. check the state file from your resource and get the typeset hash of the `hostname_configuration` part; should be similar to `hostname_configuration.XXXXXX`
3. add an `ignore_changes` section passing the above

```
resource "azurerm_api_management" "apim" {
  # ...

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      "hostname_configuration.XXXXXX",
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes such issues occur due to issues in the provider. Probably it is not storing the configuration in the state file or not retrieving the stored state for this block. Try upgrading the provider to the latest available provider and see if it sorts the issue.

If that does not solve it, you can try defining this configuration as a separate resource. As per the terraform documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management

> It's possible to define Custom Domains both within the
> azurerm_api_management resource via the hostname_configurations block
> and by using the azurerm_api_management_custom_domain resource.
> However it's not possible to use both methods to manage Custom Domains
> within an API Management Service, since there'll be conflicts.

So Please try removing that hostname_configuration block and add it as separate resource as per this documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management_custom_domain

This will most likely fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately in the same documentation we see this:
Tip: The default proxy hostname ending with .azure-api.net must not be added as it will be automatically created by Azure and ignored by Terraform.

Comment: PS. Tried the latest provide and it made no difference.

Comment: @Nick, I believe that means that you need not add the hostname_configuration or custom_domain configuration when it is azure's default domain. This PR thread seems to talk about the same issue and they suggest removing that configuration: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/10636 Can you try removing that configuration altogether and see if things work as expected?

Comment: But then the default state of `negotiate_client_certificate` for the default endpoint would be `false` when we need it to be `true`.

Comment: Oh okay. Then I'd suggest you raise this issue in their Github repo of the provider. For temporary workaround, you can consider adding lifecycle block to ignore changes of hostname_configuration . Refer: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle